# getting error while attempt to return a statement

Tags: c#, visual-studio, int, return

why it's showing an `not all code paths return a value` error while i try to return a statement
[image]

actually i want to return this

```
public int multiplication(int num, int starting, int ending)
        {
            for(int i=starting; i<=ending; i++)
            {
                return (num+int.Parse("x")+starting+int.Parse("=")+(num*starting));
            }
        }
```

Comment: What do you think `int.Parse("=")` does?

Comment: What do you think `int.Parse("x")` does?

Answer (score 2):

Too many problems with your code:

1. What method is supposed to return when `starting > ending`: **Compile time error**
2. `"x"` is not a *valid integer*: **Run time exception**
3. It seems that you don't want `this` and the method should be `static`
4. Are you really want to return `int`, not `string`?
5. There's no much sence in `for` (immediate `return`) which is equals to `if`.

   ```
   public int multiplication(int num, int starting, int ending)
   {
       for(int i=starting; i<=ending; i++)
       {
           return (num+int.Parse("x")+starting+int.Parse("=")+(num*starting));
       }
   }
   ```

I suggest that you actually want something like this:

```
    using System.Linq;

    ...

    public static string multiplication(int num, int starting, int ending) {
      return string.Join(Environment.NewLine, Enumerable
        .Range(starting, ending - starting + 1)
        .Select(i => $"{num} x {i} = {num * i}"));
    }

    ...

    Console.Write(multiplication(3, 5, 7));
```

Outcome:

```
3 x 5 = 15
3 x 6 = 18
3 x 7 = 21
```